# Postgresql Use count on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables. The first generate the condition for counting records in the second. The two tables are linked by a relation of 1:1 by Timestamp.
The problem is that the second table have many columns, and we need a count for each column that match the condition in the first column.

Example:
Tables **met** and **pot**

```sql
CREATE TABLE met (
    tstamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    h1_rad double precision,
    CONSTRAINT met_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tstamp)
)

CREATE TABLE pot (
    tstamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    c1 double precision,
    c2 double precision,
    c3 double precision,
    CONSTRAINT met_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tstamp)
)
```

**REALLY pot have 108 columns** from c1 to c108.

Tables values:

```
+   Table met             +  +    Table pot                        +
+----------------+--------+--+----------------+------+------+------+
|     tstamp     | h1_rad |  |     tstamp     |  c1  |  c2  |  c3  |
+----------------+--------+--+----------------+------+------+------+
| 20150101 00:00 | 0      |  | 20150101 00:00 | 5,5  | 3,3  | 15,6 |
| 20150101 00:05 | 1,8    |  | 20150101 00:05 | 12,8 | 15,8 | 1,5  |
| 20150101 00:10 | 15,4   |  | 20150101 00:10 | 25,4 | 4,5  | 1,4  |
| 20150101 00:15 | 28,4   |  | 20150101 00:15 | 18,3 | 63,5 | 12,5 |
| 20150101 00:20 | 29,4   |  | 20150101 00:20 | 24,5 | 78   | 17,5 |
| 20150101 00:25 | 13,5   |  | 20150101 00:25 | 12,8 | 5,4  | 18,4 |
| 20150102 00:00 | 19,5   |  | 20150102 00:00 | 11,1 | 25,6 | 6,5  |
| 20150102 00:05 | 2,5    |  | 20150102 00:05 | 36,5 | 21,4 | 45,2 |
| 20150102 00:10 | 18,4   |  | 20150102 00:10 | 1,4  | 35,5 | 63,5 |
| 20150102 00:15 | 20,4   |  | 20150102 00:15 | 18,4 | 23,4 | 8,4  |
| 20150102 00:20 | 6,8    |  | 20150102 00:20 | 16,8 | 12,5 | 18,4 |
| 20150102 00:25 | 17,4   |  | 20150102 00:25 | 25,8 | 23,5 | 9,5  |
+----------------+--------+--+----------------+------+------+------+
```

What i need is the number of rows of **pot** where value is higher than 15 when in **met** the value is higher than 15 with the same timestamp, grouped by day.

With the data supplied we need something like:

```
+----------+----+----+----+
|   day    | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+----------+----+----+----+
| 20150101 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
| 20150102 |  2 |  4 |  1 |
+----------+----+----+----+
```

How can i get this ?
Is this possible with a single query even with subquerys ?

Actually the raw data is stored every minute in others tables. The tables **met** and **pot** are summarized and filtered tables for performance.
If necessary, i can create tables with data summarized by days if this simplify the solution.

Thanks

P.D.
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with some `CASE` statements. Test for both conditions, and if true return a 1. Then `SUM()` the results using a `GROUP BY` on the `timestamp` converted to a date to get your total:

```
SELECT
    date(met.tstamp),
    SUM(CASE WHEN met.h1_rad > 15 AND pot.c1 > 15 THEN 1 END) as C1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN met.h1_rad > 15 AND pot.c2 > 15 THEN 1 END) as C2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN met.h1_rad > 15 AND pot.c3 > 15 THEN 1 END) as C3
FROM
    met INNER JOIN pot ON met.tstamp = pot.tstamp
GROUP BY date(met.tstamp)
```

Comment: Thanks JNevil,  But if i have 108 columns, is there an automatic or dynamic way to create all columns, or must create 108 lines of "SUM(CASE...."

Comment: You must create 108 lines of `Sum(Case...` Now... you could create those 108 lines programatically. Like in a bash script, or in a stored procedure, but at some point you'll have to submit 108 lines of SQL to your database for it to know what to do.